# How can one detect if a server/script is accessing their site through cURL/file_get_contents()? (excluding user-agents and IP addresses)

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

I've come across a question where a user is having difficulties accessing an image through a script (using `cURL`/`file_get_contents()`):

[How to save an image from url using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10890392/how-to-save-an-image-from-url-using-php)

The image link seems to return a 403 error when using `file_get_contents()` to request it. But in cURL, a more detailed error is returned:

> You were denied access to the system. Turn off the engine or Surf
>   Proxy, Fake IP if you really want to access. Proxy or not accepted
>   from any Web tools Intrusion Prevention System.
>
> Binh Minh Online Data Services @ 2008 - 2012

I also failed to access the same image after fiddling around with a cURL request myself. I tried changing the user-agent to my exact browsers user-agent which can successfully access the image. I've also tried the script on my personal local server, which (obviously) uses the same IP address as my browser... So as far as I know, user-agents and IP addresses are out of the situation.

How else can someone detect a script performing a request?

BTW, this is not for anything crazy. I'm just curious xD

Comment: don't steal, problem solved :-)

Comment: @Dagon `BTW, this is not for anything crazy. I'm just curious xD`

Comment: just because you say it, doesn't mean i believe you when it looks the opposite.

Comment: I'm curious on how they do it. And what got me curious was the question linked. So the target file is something that I'm not interested in (as it came from a different question, posted by someone else).

Comment: Do you have access to a web server?  If so, I would suggest putting an image on it, then accessing it via your browser and via your cURL code, looking in your access logs, and comparing them to see what the difference is.  It could be doing something nasty like, I dunno, setting a cookie and then issuing a redirect or something.  I don't know if that would work, but that's the only thing I can think of off the top of my head if your useragent is set correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is indeed a cookie that is set by JavaScript then a redirect, to the original image. The problem is that curl/fgc wont parse the html and set the cookie its only cookies set by the server that curl will store in its cookie jar.

This is the code you get before the redirect, it makes a cookie via JavaScript with no name but location.href as the value:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<HEAD>
<TITLE>http://phim.xixam.com/thumb/giotdang.jpeg</TITLE>
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;url=http://phim.xixam.com/thumb/giotdang.jpeg">
</HEAD>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function checknow() {
var today = new Date();
var expires = 3600000*1*1;
var expires_date = new Date(today.getTime() + (expires));
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
if ( ua.indexOf( "safari" ) != -1 ) { document.cookie = "location.href"; } else { document.cookie = "location.href;expires=" + expires_date.toGMTString(); }
}
</script>
<BODY>
</BODY></HTML>
```

But all is not lost, because by pre-setting/forging the cookie you can circumvent this security measure (a reason why using cookies for any kind of security is bad).

**cookie.txt**

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

phim.xixam.com  FALSE   /thumb/ FALSE   1338867990      location.href
```

So the finnished curl script would look something like:

```
<?php
function curl_get($url){
    $return = '';
    (function_exists('curl_init')) ? '' : die('cURL Must be installed!');

    //Forge the cookie
    $expire = time()+3600000*1*1;
    $cookie =<<<COOKIE
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

phim.xixam.com  FALSE   /thumb/ FALSE   $expire     location.href

COOKIE;
    file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt',$cookie);

    //Browser Masquerade cURL request
    $curl = curl_init();
    $header[0] = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/json,application/xhtml+xml,";
    $header[0] .= "text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5";
    $header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0";
    $header[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
    $header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300";
    $header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
    $header[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5";
    $header[] = "Pragma: ";

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0 Firefox/5.0');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    //Pass the referer check
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://xixam.com/forum.php');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    $html = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $html;
}

$image = curl_get('http://phim.xixam.com/thumb/giotdang.jpeg');

file_put_contents('test.jpg',$image);
?>
```

The only way to stop a crawler is to log all your visitors ips in your database and increment a value based on visits per ip, then once a week or so look at the top hits by ip and then do a reverse lookup of the ip and see if its from a hosting provider if so block it at your firewall or in htaccess, other then that you cant really stop the request to a resource if its publicly available as any hurdle can be overcome.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Wow, when I posted my comment above, I honestly thought it was kind of grasping, and that the real reason it wasn't working was probably something the OP overlooked.  That's some awesome follow-up and testing!  Hopefully the OP will accept and upvote your answer, you definitely get an upvote from me!